# Хороший код JavaScript

Tags: jquery, хороший-тон, javascript, style-guide

1. Как лучше именовать переменные и функции?
2. Как комментировать код?
3. Чего лучше не делать?
4. ...

Иными словами, интересует всё то, что облегчит поддержку кода как автору кода, так и другим программистам.

Интересуют JavaScript и jQuery.

Comment: А мне казалось, что это можно сделать лишь одним способом.....

     Как комментировать код?

Comment: прочитайте книгу JavaScript Patterns - всё изложение в книге сделано ввиде того как надо писать код, а как не надо

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[**Google JavaScript Style Guide**](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javascriptguide.xml)

Answer (score 13):

*В коментарии не влезло, посему пришлось писать, как ответ.*

Знаете, какое одно из главных качеств, которым должен обладать любой программист? Это - логика. Если вам это свойство не чуждо, то попробуйте ответить на свои же вопросы.

1. Функции (да и переменные) должны именоваться осмысленно, чтоб увидя ее, можно было бы догадаться, что она делает или же, чтоб её можно было легко найти. Логично? Думаю да.
2. Коментировать куски кода, желательно простым человеческим языком: кратко и информативно. Вроде бы тоже логики не лишено.
3. Не изобретать колесо, а знать синтаксис, логику, методы и прочие особенности языка.

А в остальном, логично было бы в поисковике набрать что-то вроде: "*Правила хорошего тона в программировании*", "*Красивый код*", "*Правильное оформление кода*", etc. Потому как перечислить все тонкости, отвечая на вопрос, достаточно накладно.

Comment: С тремя пунктами согласен. Только это общие пожелания. А хочется именно деталей типа следующего:
    
    Именуйте functionNamesLikeThis, variableNamesLikeThis, ClassNamesLikeThis, EnumNamesLikeThis, methodNamesLikeThis и SYMBOLIC_CONSTANTS_LIKE_THIS.

Понимаю, что расписывать все тонкости накладно - хотел увидеть то, знакомство с чем помогает более опытным товарищам в разработке. 

За поисковые фразы - спасибо. Буду читать.

Comment: @Khvorostin, трижды подумайте, прежде чем писать такие вот (beginOfDataInMainBuffer) идентификаторы. 

Часто кристальная чистота алгоритма, размером со страничку, записанного такими словами, напрочь улетучивается.

Comment: @avp А еще чаще бывает, что кристальная чистота кода, который был записан с помощью имен типа `mainBufferDataBegin`, напрочь улетучивается, если заменить их на `x`, `y`, `kkk` и `tr_1_2_j`.

Comment: Во всем надо чувствовать меру. 

Скажем, kkk и tr_1_2_j это безусловно перебор, а x и y вполне допустимо в качестве очевидных "промежуточных" переменных.

Конечно, основные переменные и функции должны иметь хорошие, понятные имена.

--

_quicksort, pbase, total_elems, size, cmp, arg, base_ptr, max_thresh, lo, hi, STACK_SIZE, stack, top, PUSH, STACK_NOT_EMPTY, left_ptr, right_ptr ...

Это из GNU libc qsort().

Answer (score 3):

Насчёт чего лучше не делать - вот хорошая мини-презентация:

- [Ineffective JavaScript](http://eamodeorubio.github.com/ineffectivejs/)

Answer (score 2):

Для начала почитайте ["Чистый код" Роберта Мартина](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/5011068/) (или найдите то, что вам больше понравится), ваши вопросы относятся к программированию вцелом, не только к JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

В дополнение, если крепкие нервы: JsLint к вашим услугам. 
Если верить их описанию, он как раз и оценивает "хорошесть" кода

Comment: Плюсую, хотя статический анализ и нерешает пункты 1 и 2 вопроса автора.

Comment: Надо признать, что отчасти-таки решает. Скажем так: если они проименованны все в едином стиле, то статической проверки "читабельности" вполне хватит.

Comment: Первую проблему можно решить, например, с помощью **[Google Closure Linter.][1]**

[1]: https://developers.google.com/closure/utilities/docs/linter_howto

Answer (score 1):

Крошка сын к отцу пришёл, и спросила кроха:
- Что такое хорошо и что такое плохо?

[JavaScript Patterns Collection](http://shichuan.github.com/javascript-patterns/#general-patterns)

Answer (score 1):

Этот навык приходит с опытом и оттачивается годами, если конечно уделять этому время и внимание, глядя как пишут другие, читать статьи посвященные данной тематике, а где-то и сам приходишь к пониманию как делать правильно и лучше. Поэтому все перечислить одним ответом на ваш вопрос просто невозможно, могу лишь дать ссылку на руководство где я собрал некоторые мысли о том как писать хороший код. Может быть какие-то приемы будут вам полезны: [руководство по оформлению JavaScript кода](https://www.gitbook.com/book/sultan99/js-code-style/details)

Главное уделять этому внимание, время от времени гуглить и читать об этом. Лично сам я так и делаю, поэтому и попал на ваш вопрос, подглядеть, что советуют люди, какие новые приемы по улучшению коду придумали и так далее.

Answer (score 0):

Ещё рекомендации:

- Оригинал: [Airbnb JavaScript Style Guide](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript)
- Перевод: [Стиль написания кода на JavaScript для Uprock](https://github.com/uprock/javascript): Перевод и расширение "Airbnb JavaScript Style Guide"

Плюс [статья на Хабре о этом руководстве](http://habrahabr.ru/company/uprock/blog/204848/).